# What was the first language compiler to support subtype polymorphism?

Tags: programming, compilers

I'm trying to understand the history of [Dependency Injection](http://w3sdesign.com/?gr=u01&ugr=proble#gf) in compiled languages, *as an intentional feature of the language*. The Wikipedia article on the subject is decidedly Java focused, but I know earlier languages supported OOP with interfaces (e.g. pure virtual methods in C++ abstract classes).

According to the design pattern described in the link, a clear requirement on the language compiler is support for  something akin to `type interface`.

**Edit**: Then, polymorphism is used to morph the concrete, run-time object into the expected abstract class type used by the client.

> A class (Client) accepts the objects it requires automatically at run-time.
>
> - A class can use objects solely through their interfaces (ServiceA,ServiceB) and doesn't have to care about how the objects are created.
> - This greatly simplifies classes and makes them easier to implement, change, test, and reuse.

Which OOP language compiler first provided this capability directly in the language's system of typing objects?

*NOTE*: I'm not really looking for speculations on how one might hack this in assembly, C, Fortran, etc., though that would still be interesting if it relates to the history of the feature's evolution.

Comment: > The first complete [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) compiler, written in Lisp, was implemented in 1962 by Tim Hart and Mike Levin at MIT.

Comment: True. But a language, like Lisp, supporting first-class functions, doesn't need this design pattern, right?

Comment: But that's just the point, it's a design pattern. Just because it's trivial to do in the language doesn't mean it's not a valid design pattern. DI is more an external instantiation and binding mechanism than anything else. Lisp historically didn't apply this pattern, mostly because it's primary use is in testing, which wasn't common back in the day. Obj-C relied heavily on the Factory pattern for object creation, and DI is just an extension off of that. So, I guess I'm not clear as to what you're really asking here. I can't name any language that provides DI natively. Java doesn't.

Comment: @WillHartung I think its derailing the question to consider languages that aren't OOP, or don't use classes, or don't have the same concept of strict typing for an interface, or don't need compilation.

Comment: I don't see what's so special about this "design pattern'.  I don't know of any any OOP language that requires doing anything special to create an object independently of a class that might use it.

Comment: @RossRidge DI is not about modularizing classes, per se. It's about resolving which class gets used at run-time instead of at compile time.

Comment: I don't see where the page you linked says that. It's about creating **objects** at run-time independent of the class that uses them. I think you're also misinterpreting the use of the word "interface" in the page you linked to mean Java interfaces, not the more general use of the word.

Comment: The problem is realy, that this is about a design pattern. design patterns are independant of languages, they are methods of programming, not coding. And using DI is not in any way tied to OO - at least not more than adding two numbers is.

Comment: @RossRidge From the linked page: "A reusable class should avoid creating the objects it requires directly (and often it doesn't know at compile-time which class to instantiate) so that it can accept the objects it requires at run-time (from an injector object)."

Comment: @Raffzahn I worded the question very precisely: OO, compiled, strict typing, interface classes. Yes, if you ignore half the words in my question, then it is open to a multitude of answers.

Comment: Yes **objects** not classes.

Comment: @RossRidge Ok, some semantics. Compile-time classes that are abstract (i.e. interfaces) become the run-time objects used by the client.

Comment: I think you're more narrowly defining the pattern then the page you linked is. It doesn't use the word "abstract" anywhere.

Comment: @BrianH It's like you want one very specific name, one you already have in mind, as general criteria it doesn't make any sense. So what about just telling which product you want to present?

Comment: @RossRidge Which compiled languages have you personally used for DI? I've used a few, and all of them needed an abstract class treated as an interface type to implement DI straightforwardly.

Comment: @Raffzahn From personal experience, could be C++ or Objective-C. I've only ever used DI in 3 compiled languages - the other being Java. Which languages have you used DI in?

Comment: I think design patterns are crap, they're solutions in search of problems, so I've never consciously used this one or any other. However, your interpretation of the this particular design pattern doesn't agree with that of the author you linked. As is, your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps it would be better if you simply just asked what language first implemented whatever specific features you're insisting are necessary.

Comment: @RossRidge Referring back to the question "According to the design pattern described in the link, a clear requirement on the language compiler is support for something akin to type interface". Is this your point of contention?

Comment: Oh, just remembered, I've used DI in Golang (hard not to). Golang has a type name "interface". Taking how it is used in Golang, and stepping backwards to when such a type was first introduced in a compiled OO language, should be the answer, I think.

Comment: @BrianH Oh, so JavaScript doesn't count? What do OOP, Interfaces, Classes, Compiling, or Typing have to do with any of this? DI is about delegating "object" creation (for a broad definition of Object). DI formalized the creation of a "configurable factory" for lack of a better term, but there was nothing to stop something like Lisp, or any of the early dynamic languages, from implementing a DI mechanism. No doubt, many did ad hoc versions in applications. And I won't bring up changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH as a crude DI mechanism to dynamically change what implementations are run at runtime.

Comment: @WillHartung I am not trying to convince anyone that DI can only be done in one way. I'm asking when OO languages/compilers started to have the necessary ingredients to do it straightforwardly.

Comment: @RossRidge You say "I think design patterns are crap". I'm not trying to convince anyone otherwise, and that is above my pay grade. Maybe take it up with the GoF.

Comment: @BrianH you have to distinguish between Compiler and Language, them's different. What's an example of any language that you know of that meets the criteria you are seeking, since you're interested in the "first" or "early" versions. What's a current, or later language as an example? And "can do it" and "did do it" are also quite different.

Comment: I am in no way interested in discussing the merits of this design pattern or design patterns in general. I was just answering the question you asked me.

Comment: @WillHartung Repeating myself, but examples of compilers I have personally used for DI include: Go, Java, C++, Objective-C.

Comment: @BrianH Donning my Pedantic Hat, the Java, C++, and Obj-C (I can't speak to Go) compilers do not support DI. The language semantics support DI. None of these have compilers or runtimes dedicated to facilitating DI as a concept.

Comment: @WillHartung Ok, "language semantics support it" is clear. I wanted to limit the answer to compiled languages, so that's why I keep using both words.

Comment: I've had to vote to close because I'm not clear why the question is about. It talks about polymorphism in the title, abstract interfaces and dependency injection. These are not the same concepts even though they are related. You can do dependency injection without fully abstract classes/interfaces. In any case Simula 67 had something similar, so that may be the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simula 67 supports abstract types so I think it could support dependency injection, I'm just not sure if it was ever used as a programming pattern.

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Abstract_type#Simula

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the VIRTUAL definition represents a type usable within a client class, or not? To my understanding, some languages just treat abstract classes as templates for subclassing, rather than as interfaces.

Comment: @BrianH If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula and the example of Line and Glyph, Simula satisfies the base requirements for something that can support DI (Since Char is an implementation of Glyph, but Line is specified as using Glyphs, not Char). It's also recognized as the first object oriented language, so this would seem to be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @WillHartung I agree. Thanks for pointing it out. Now I'm just wondering if there is such a thing as a Simula compiler...

Comment: @BrianH http://www.edelweb.eu/Simula/ "WHEN looking INTO the Internet near 2006, documentation FOR old SIMULA compilers AND even the original language definitions are difficult TO find." What makes you think it wasn't compiled? Why does compiling matter? Lisp can be compiled and interpreted. C can be compiled and interpret. BASIC can be compiled and interpreted. Some argue Java is interpreted. What difference does it make at a language level?

Comment: @WillHartung Lol, dude! Am I not allowed to have an interest in compiler history? I just didn't want to assume Simula was compiled without checking.

Comment: I did read one of the early simula papers and thought it looked likely DI was possible (not sure it was the expected pattern to use with Simula) I might have a fuller look via the ACM library as it might have some better examples.

Answer (score -4):

Hmm. The main problem here is that this is about a design pattern, which are ideas how programming can/should be done. This is already full implemented if developer just follow that path. No 'real' tool needed, even less a language. More so, language extensions or preprocessing scripts can handle the requirement independant of a certain language.

**Every language that can pass function pointers can do so.**

Last but not least, the basic idea is something that was used in software development for a long time. Handing over function pointer, nowadays called 'callbacks' are anything but new. Like in data base application were a search function could be called and get a filter handed.

Or standard screen handler that got called with a screen definition and, depending on the job a wariable number of call backs to read data, check data or write data back into the data base. Sounds much like your case, doesn't it? Programmign wise would that be handled by pseudo code (Macros) to be interpreted at compiletime inserting all necessary unctions.

Then again, you already mentioned that there is a huge gray area between inserting a pointer and a dedicated language construct, which is al well defined to be made for the purpose as deign pattern. If you want a reliable answer, on tools and/or languages, the topic does need a better definition how to meet your criteria.

Comment: @BrianH While the question uses a lot of words to try to do this, technically you can do this in a powerful enough assembly language (TASM, MASM, LLVM, etc.). You have to build the abstraction yourself, but you can then write code using that abstraction. To be pedantic, Raffzahn wasn't right in saying that _every_ language that can pass function pointers can do this; but the vast, vast majority that have function pointers do support enough other features to make the implementation of this design pattern possible. (Though the answer isn't v.helpful.) Does this help to narrow down your question?

Comment: @BrianH If you write something like "what language compilers had explicit support for" and clarify what you're asking for, I don't see why it can't be re-opened. Closing isn't a punishment nor a final state; it's merely to allow the question to be revised without encouraging answers like Raffzahn's here (no blame assigned).